# Building Model Associations in Factory Girl Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

Here is the relevant section from my models:

```
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
  validate :quantity, :more_than_stock,  :message => "more than in stock is reserved." 

 def more_than_stock
    errors.add(:quantity, "should be less than in stock") if self.quantity > self.product.stock
  end
```

I keep erroring out on this line: `errors.add(:quantity, "should be less than in stock") if self.quantity > self.product.stock` with regards to the `.stock` method.

The error I keep getting is: `1) Error:
test_product_id_must_be_a_number(CartRowTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method 'stock' for nil:NilClass` in my tests.

It seems to me that my test suite doesn't know about the `.stock` method on product.

However, here is my product factory:

```
factory :product do
    name 'Cholecap - 100mg'
    limit 3
    stock 10
  end
```

and my cart_row factory:

```
 factory :cart_row do
    product
    cart
    quantity 3
  end
```

Here is the relevant portion of my unit test that throws the error:

```
def setup
    @cart_row = FactoryGirl.create(:cart_row)
  end

  test "product_id must not be blank" do
    @cart_row.product_id = "         "
    assert !@cart_row.valid?
  end

test "product_id must be a number" do
     @cart_row.product_id = '234'
    assert !@cart_row.valid?
  end
```

What do I need to do to let the test suite know about the .stock method?

Comment: actually it appears that your cart row doesn't know about your product? Since it says no method .stock on nil.  What does your cart_row model look ? specifically the associations.

Comment: @Doon added associations above.

Comment: you don't show  test_product_id_must_be_a_number, which is what is failing.  But if you are setting the product_id to be invalid, it isn't going to be able to pull the stock since there isn't an associated product. Does it fail if you just build a complete one?

Comment: @Doon I've added the test_product_id_must_... and you're right. I'm setting it to be invalid. What's the best way to make this work?

Comment: you don't need to test that the product_id is a number, you should test that the product is valid? but you will need to modify the validaation to make sure there is an associated product before you try to query the quantity on hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set product_id to invalid value you can't make test suite know about the #stock method. If you realy want make these test pass try this code:

```
belongs_to :cart
belongs_to :product
validates_associated :product
validate :quantity, :more_than_stock, message: "more than in stock is reserved." , if: "product.respond_to? :stock"

def more_than_stock
  errors.add(:quantity, "should be less than in stock") if quantity > product.stock
end
```